# Mobile version of my website only loads correctly after refresh

Tags: css, mobile, padding, page-refresh

I created a responsive website with media queries for the mobile version but it doesn't load part of the css for the links on the homepage but then corrects itself after being refreshed. Can someone help me understand what's wrong and why it does that?

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    .Design-projects {
    padding-left: 8%;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
  }

    .design-projects-level-1 {
    padding-left: 8%;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

    .design-projects-level-2 {
    padding-left: 8%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 15%;
  }

    .design-projects-level-3 {
    padding-left: 8%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 15%;
    }

    .eventsgeneral {
      text-align: right;
    }

    .Events {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding-left: 55%;
      margin-right: 0;
      padding-bottom: 5%;
    }

    .design-projects-level-4 {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-right: 64%;
      padding-left: 0;
    }

    .design-projects-level-5 {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 64%;
      padding-top: 15%;
    }

    .design-projects-level-6 {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 64%;
      padding-top: 15%;
    }
}
```

```html
<h2 className="Design-projects">DESIGN PROJECTS  </h2>

  <div className="design-projects-level-1">
 <Link to="/Soundcloudredesign">01. Redesigning Soundcloud </Link></div>

   <div className="design-projects-level-2">
        <Link to="/ramenshop">02. The Ramen Shop</Link> </div>

    <div className="design-project-level-3">
        <Link to="/otts">03. Ott's Exotic Plants</Link> </div>


    <div className="eventsgeneral">
    <h2 className="Events">EVENTS  </h2>

    <div className="design-projects-link-level-4">
        <Link to="/westhollywood">01. West Hollywood EDITION</Link></div>

    <div className="design-projects-link-level-5">
        <Link to="/noblepanacea">02. Noble Panacea Global Brand Launch</Link></div>

    <div className="design-projects-link-level-6">
        <Link to="/ellenvonunwerth">03. Ellen von Unwerth at Fotografiska</Link></div>
  </div>
```

When it first loads, the links look like this:

[image]

[image]

But it should look like this (however, it only looks like this after I refresh the page):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but first, you should improve your coding. You don't need to create a new CSS class for each of your item, especially if it is exactly the same.

You encounter that issue because your CSS code is not useful.

Below, you will find the code that you are looking for:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.Design-projects {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    padding-left: 8%;
}

.design-projects-item{

    padding-left: 8%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.eventsgeneral {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 8%;
}

.Events {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.events-item {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
}
```

```html
<h2 class="Design-projects">DESIGN PROJECTS</h2>

<div class="design-projects-item">
  <Link to="/Soundcloudredesign">01. Redesigning Soundcloud </Link>
</div>

<div class="design-projects-item">
  <Link to="/ramenshop">02. The Ramen Shop</Link>
</div>

<div class="design-projects-item">
  <Link to="/otts">03. Ott's Exotic Plants</Link>
</div>


<div class="eventsgeneral">

  <h2 class="Events">EVENTS</h2>

  <div class="events-item">
    <Link to="/westhollywood">01. West Hollywood EDITION</Link>
  </div>

  <div class="events-item">
    <Link to="/noblepanacea">02. Noble Panacea Global Brand Launch</Link>
  </div>

  <div class="events-item">
    <Link to="/ellenvonunwerth">03. Ellen von Unwerth at Fotografiska</Link>
  </div>

</div>
```